# How does the resource server know which algorithm to use to verify a JWT?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have created a token using any of the algorithm say HS256, when this is passed to resource server, I can see the implementation like below

```
TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
{
ValidAudience = ActiveDirectory.audience,
ValidIssuer = ActiveDirectory.issuer,
ValidateLifetime = true,
ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
LifetimeValidator = this.LifetimeValidator,
IssuerSigningKey = new 
SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ActiveDirectory.clientSecret))
};
```

Notice here that while validating token, No algorithm is passed (it must be HS256 to compare hashing).

Now lets say, I have changed algorithm while creating token from HS256 to HS512, Here my resource server still validates the token successfully ?

Could anyone help me specifying algorithm on resource server to validate against token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information which algorithm was used for signing and has to be used for verification is in the header of the JWT:

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

Therefore you don't configure the algorithm in the `TokenValidationParameters`. When the backend receives a token, it gets the information about the algorithm from the JWT header and then uses that algorithm to verify the token with the configured key or secret.

As long as you have the right keys/secrets (and also the right key type, e.g. when you change to asymmetric algorithms), verification should work.

As it is also possible to set the algorithm claim `"alg"` to `none`, which means the token is not signed, you should add a setting that forbids unsigned tokens:

```
RequireSignedTokens = true,
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer !
See this line of code 
IssuerSigningKey = new 
SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ActiveDirectory.clientSecret))

here we are using same client_secret to verify token but without any algorithm. Where we are passing algorithm to verify ?

Comment: @AmardeepKumarAgrawal: updated my answer to make it clearer.